# Ffmpeg - Codec 'mp2' (86016) is not supported by the bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'

Tags: ffmpeg, bitstream

I'm trying to dump a video streaming on local file using this syntax:

```
ffmpeg -i "http://test.com/videoxxx" -c copy -bsf:v aac_adtstoasc -t 10 c:\\temp\\out.mp4 -loglevel debug
```

It works pretty fine but recently I've encounter specific error:

```
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] DTS 165134700 < 165199500 out of order
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] Non-increasing DTS in stream 0: packet 249 with DTS 165199500, packet 250 with DTS 165134700
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] Continuity check failed for pid 0 expected 12 got 11
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] Continuity check failed for pid 4096 expected 12 got 11
[h264 @ 00000232c9571980] ct_type:0 pic_struct:1
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] Continuity check failed for pid 256 expected 8 got 10
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] Continuity check failed for pid 17 expected 10 got 5
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] Continuity check failed for pid 257 expected 2 got 12
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] PES packet size mismatch
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] Non-increasing DTS in stream 1: packet 207 with DTS 165121380, packet 208 with DTS 164212020
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5016000 microseconds st:1
[mpegts @ 00000232c9568f40] After avformat_find_stream_info() pos: 799667 bytes read:822628 seeks:0 frames:463
Input #0, mpegts, from 'http://test.com/videoxxx':
  Duration: N/A, start: 1824.578000, bitrate: N/A
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100], 252, 1/90000: Video: h264 (High), 1 reference frame ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first, left), 720x576 [SAR 16:11 DAR 20:11], 0/1, 25 fps, 50 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](pol), 211, 1/90000: Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s
Successfully opened the file.
Parsing a group of options: output url c:\temp\out.mp4.
Applying option c (codec name) with argument copy.
Applying option bsf:a (A comma-separated list of bitstream filters) with argument aac_adtstoasc.
Applying option t (record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video) with argument 30.
Successfully parsed a group of options.
Opening an output file: c:\temp\out.mp4.
[file @ 00000232ca120e80] Setting default whitelist 'file,crypto'
Successfully opened the file.
[AVBSFContext @ 00000232ca6e5780] Codec 'mp2' (86016) is not supported by the bitstream filter 'aac_adtstoasc'. Supported codecs are: aac (86018) 
Error initializing bitstream filter: aac_adtstoasc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
[AVIOContext @ 00000232c95ecfc0] Statistics: 0 seeks, 0 writeouts
[AVIOContext @ 00000232c9574780] Statistics: 822628 bytes read, 0 seeks
```

Is it possible to use specific FFMPEG command avoid bitstream filter issue?
I've tryed with:

```
-vcodec copy -t 20 c:\\temp\\out.mp4 -loglevel debug
```

and:

```
c:a copy -t 10 c:\\temp\\out.mp4 -loglevel debug
```

but I'm able to create a cutted mp4 with 1 frame and audio cut after 1/2 sec.

Is it also a way to debug the source? 
Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As its name suggests the `aac_adtstoasc` is used only for AAC audio streams with ADTS headers, like AAC in a MPEG-2 TS container or raw ADTS AAC. Probe the input format beforehand to decide whether to add the filter or not. It should also be `-bsf:a` instead of `v`.

Comment: Unless disabled*, muxers will auto-insert relevant BSFs. *or using `tee`. So manual specification is not required.

Comment: hi @gyan, what do you mean exactly by "tee"? is there any specific syntax I can insert in my command line? thx

Comment: Yuo don't need to set `-bsf:a aac_adtstoasc`. ffmpeg will do it for you when applicable.